# MySQL entries appear blank after PHP submits data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues with my PHP, in that it is making the data input by a form on my webpage appear blank.

Here's my PHP:

```
 <?php
//the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form
//input.php
mysql_connect("localhost", "bashletc_upload", "fakepassword", "bashletc_font-   database");//database connection



//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO `bashletc_font-database`.`fonts`
            (filename, filelocation)
            VALUES
            ('$filename',
            '$filelocation')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>File has been logged.<br> All your font are belong to us.");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input Failure.");
}
?>
```

EDIT: Here's the HTML form.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p> Please enter this information into our public <br> database so others can use this font!<br> This feature is not implemented yet.</p>
File-Name: <input type="text" name="$filename"><br>
File-Location: <input type="text" name="$filelocation">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: did you checked `mysql_error()`? you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: What are `$filename` and `$filelocation` the moment you are inserting it? Guessing you missed to get those variables from `POST` or `GET` Array.

Comment: @dognose Am I not getting the variables from this form in my html?  

`<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p> Please enter this information into our public <br> database so others can use this font!<br> This feature is not implemented yet.</p>
File-Name: <input type="text" name="$filename"><br>
File-Location: <input type="text" name="$filelocation">
<input type="submit">
</form>`

Comment: As pointed out above by @dognose, you haven't grabbed the `$filename` and `$filelocation` variables. In your HTML, an input should look like `<input type="text" name="myVariable" />`, then in your PHP the corresponding value can be taken from `$variable = $_POST['myVariable'];`.